# A chart Js error issue are occured in my Laravel other page?

Tags: laravel, chart.js

when I created a chart in my dashboard is working fine. But after when I go to another page like the post page, Then this chart error occurred. how can I solve this.
I have use this footer page in all pages. This footer shows an error in other page.

```
Undefined variable: chart (View: C:\wamp64\www\AdBlog\resources\views\admin\layouts\footer.blade.php)
```

And this is my Footer page for all admin page

```
 <footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      <b>Version</b> 2.3.8
    </div>
    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2019-{{ Carbon\carbon::now()->year }} <a href="http://facebook.com">NS Tech</a>.</strong> All rights
    reserved.
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script>
      $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Morris.js charts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/morris/morris.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- datepicker -->
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/dist/js/app.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->

    <script src="{{ asset('admin/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js') }}"></script> 
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/dist/js/demo.js') }}"></script>

       <!--Chart js -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    {!! $chart->script() !!}
    {!! $linechart->script() !!}

    @section('footerSection')
    @show
  </footer>
```

This is my controller page for `chart.js`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model\user\User;
use App\Model\user\category;
use App\Model\user\post;
use App\Model\user\tag;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Charts\ViewsChart;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $userCount = User::count();

        $publishedPostsCount = post::where('created_at', '!=', null)->count();

        $publishedCategoriesCount = tag::where('created_at', '!=', null)->count();

        $publishedTagsCount = category::where('created_at', '!=', null)->count();

       //for bar chart
        $chart = new ViewsChart;
        $chart->labels(['tags', 'category', 'posts', 'users']);
        $dataset = $chart->dataset('Number of Records', 'bar', [$publishedTagsCount, $publishedCategoriesCount, $publishedPostsCount, $userCount]);
        $dataset->backgroundColor(collect(['#7158e2','#3ae374', '#ff3838', '#7158e2']));
        $dataset->color(collect(['#7d5fff','#32ff7e', '#ff4d4d', '#7158e2']));

       //for doughnut chart1
        $linechart = new ViewsChart;
        $linechart->labels(['tags', 'category', 'posts', 'users']);
        $dataset = $linechart->dataset('Number of Records', 'doughnut', [$publishedTagsCount, $publishedCategoriesCount, $publishedPostsCount, $userCount]);
        $dataset->backgroundColor(collect(['#ff6384','#36a2eb', '#cc65fe', '#ffce56']));
        $dataset->color(collect(['#7d5fff','#32ff7e', '#ff4d4d', '#7158e2']));

        return view('admin.home')->with([
            'user_count' => $userCount, 
            'published_post_count' => $publishedPostsCount,
            'published_category_count' => $publishedCategoriesCount,
            'published_Tag_count' => $publishedTagsCount,
            'chart' => $chart,
            'linechart' => $linechart
        ]);
    }

}
```

`web.php`

```
//Admin Routes (web.php):

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function(){
    Route::get('admin/home','HomeController@index')->name('admin.home');
    //Route::resource('admin/post','Admin\PostController'); -> uses this if not resource controller
            //User routes
    Route::resource('admin/user','UserController');
            //Role routes
    Route::resource('admin/role','RoleController');
            //Permission routes
    Route::resource('admin/permission','PermissionController');
            //Post routes
    Route::resource('admin/post','PostController');
            //tag routes
    Route::resource('admin/tag','TagController');
            //category routes
    Route::resource('admin/category','CategoryController');
            //Admin Routes 1
    Route::get('admin-login','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
            // Admin Routes2 copy 1,2 from Router.php auth code and edit yourself 
    Route::post('admin-login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
});
```

Comment: what chart package are you using? and can you show the controller code that is returning this view?

Comment: Chart.js package i have used.

Comment: Chart.js is a javascript library, where is the `{!! $chart->script() !!}` coming from? what Laravel package is that?

Comment: I have used this package: composer require consoletvs/charts:6.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in `footer.blade.php` to check if the current route name is `admin.home`

```php
@if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'admin.home')
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    {!! $chart->script() !!}
    {!! $linechart->script() !!}
@endif
```

more info about [Accessing The Current Route](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#accessing-the-current-route)

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Saly thanks i was about to edit it `Route::currentRouteName()`

Comment: After applying this method. Charts not loading. And the current route name of my page is **admin/home**.

Comment: it'll work only if you are authenticated + in the same route name (dashboard)

Comment: Glad to help, could you please accept my answer or upvote it at least. @NeerajTangariya

Comment: okk I will. But at this time my reputation is below 15. When it cross the 15 above. I will vote and accept this.

Comment: Okay, Thanks dude, now you've passed 21 @NeerajTangariya